# HttpClient usage in webapp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

my question is should we use only one object of Http client for every request we make to webapi or create a new object every time.
i am not sure which will be good to go with.

like can create a  base controller class which can be inherited by all the controllers and there i am having a http client object which i an reusing for all the requests.

```
 private HttpClient HttpClient
        {
            get
            {
                if (_httpClient != null) return _httpClient;
                _httpClient = new HttpClient();
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove(keyAuthorization);
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(keyAuthorization, AuthenticationToken);
                return _httpClient;
            }
        }
```

or for every new request create a new http client object and then dispose that object.

```
  using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient( ))
                    {
                        c.GetAsync("url");
                    }
```

Comment: _httpClient = new HttpClient(); and HttpClient c = new HttpClient( ) both are creating new objects. Reference variable is different in second case though

Comment: You should not create again and again; as long as you using await ..